# Sorting a column with only min value

Tags: sorting, tcl

I have this kind of file :

```
abak 1 2 3 4
b.b   2 3 4 5 
abak 2 5 6 2 
b.b  -1.2 3 4 6
cc   3 4 5 6
```

And I want

```
abak 1 2 3 4
b.b  -1.2 3 4 6
cc   3 4 5 6
```

A sorted by column 2 file with only the min value for the column

As a first step I tried to sort the lines with :

```
set file [open "[lindex $argv 0]" "r"]

    foreach line [split [read $file] "\n"] {
            lappend records [split $line " "]
    }
    set records [lsort -index 1 -real $records]

    foreach record $records {
            puts [join $record " "]
    }
}
```

but i go the error :

```
expected floating-point number but got ""
    while executing
"lsort -index 1 -real $records"
```

column 2 have not all floating number, but it's a real number;
Why it cannot work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much a question about creating and manipulating a data structure. This is how I would approach it:

```
set fid [open filename r]
set data [dict create]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    set fields [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $line]
    dict lappend data [lindex $fields 0] [lrange $fields 1 end]
}
dict for {key values} $data {
    puts [format "%-5s %s" $key [lindex [lsort -real -index 0 $values] 0]]
}
```

outputs

```
abak  1 2 3 4
b.b   -1.2 3 4 6
cc    3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Powerful solution, I am not very familiar with dict.

Comment: One great advantage of a dict over an array is that a dict maintains the insertion order of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your key problem is that `split` is not the right way to extract those records: it converts multi-space sequences into empty elements. Instead, you want to use this:

```
lappend records [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
```

That will convert the line into its list of non-space sequences. (Yes, you lose the spaces when you reconvert; that's usually not too big a problem but you can handle it if you need to.) The rest of your code looks fine enough.

Comment: hi, the list looks much more good : {abak 1 2 3 4} {bb 2 3 4 5} {abak 2 5 6 2} {bb -1.2 3 4 6} {} but the problem is the same :
element 1 missing from sublist ""
    while executing
"lsort -index 1 -real $records"